# How to send Ajax request like Magento

Tags: php, magento

I debug in Magento admin. When i search/filter in table/grid, it send a ajax request without parameter, but it still do right. How they do this, where it get data to search/filter?

```
Request URL:http://192.168.1.29/magento/index.php/admincp/customer/grid/key/09469734cfa212fcbeea780d83672fa3/filter/bmFtZT1zeiZjdXN0b21lcl9zaW5jZSU1QmxvY2FsZSU1RD1lbl9VUw==/?ajax=true&isAjax=true
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview parsed
POST /magento/index.php/admincp/customer/grid/key/09469734cfa212fcbeea780d83672fa3/filter/bmFtZT1zeiZjdXN0b21lcl9zaW5jZSU1QmxvY2FsZSU1RD1lbl9VUw==/?ajax=true&isAjax=true HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.29
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 44
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
X-Prototype-Version: 1.7
Origin: http://192.168.1.29
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://192.168.1.29/magento/index.php/admincp/customer/index/key/84d12064a10d7bbefb735e8d1e3db74b/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: frontend=6rp4ia821dqe6i6q2h4lmtovk7; adminhtml=jinn3k6khrc1u7te4s9cq4pui5
Query String Parametersview parsed
ajax=true&isAjax=true
Form Dataview parsed
internal_customer=&form_key=eUx2oZyidqOwcPdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `filter` parameter with something like base64 value `filter/bmFtZT1zeiZjdXN0b21lcl9zaW5jZSU1QmxvY2FsZSU1RD1lbl9VUw==` in your request.
Sure, it takes parameters from form.

You could also disable secret key for magento admin by System/Configuration/Advanced/Admin/Security/Add Secret Key to URLs which would help you investigate admin panel.